# Is it possible to create a adobe air android app that takes control the phones ring and creates it own based off of a text message?

Tags: android, apache-flex, air, flash-builder, air-android

Good afternoon 
I was wandering if this is possible to do with adobe air. I have a interesting idea to create a app with air that creates a ring based on the content of a text message but i was wandering is this even possible. I am learning adobe air and have created a much simpler application and was thing about going on to create this but i would like to know if it is even possible to do or if i would be trying to do something that isn't possible. Could i do it with air 4.6 with java library? Yes or no answer would be fine. 
Thank you very much for you help!
Justin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, the native extensions available in 4.6 (full-release available Nov. 29, 2011) would allow for this. Until then, I'm afraid not.

Comment: all that requires is AIR 3 in a custom Flex SDK, which you can merge with 2.5 manually now if you want:  http://blogs.cynergysystems.com/2011/09/20/creating-a-custom-flex-4-5-sdk-to-target-flash-11-and-air-3/

Comment: Ok thank you! ya i was guessing that they didn't have some APIs for what i wanted to do. Witch means it looks like I'm going to try and learn another programming haha Its quite the learning curve for all of this. Thank Your for you halp!